# Dungeon Defenders use of Invisibility in PvP with the Huntress

Tags: dungeon-defenders

In PvP, will the other player you are fighting be able to see you when using her invisibility? I know you still can see her in team plays. I haven't played in PvP yet.

Comment: I don't know if you can actually get mana in pvp, but if you could, they'd know where you were as soon as you attacked anyway.

Comment: Wait, there is PvP in Dungeon Defenders?!

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility), Invisibility does not make the Huntress invisible to players.

> In PvP, Invisibility prevents creatures from seeing the Huntress but does not prevent players from doing so.